# JavaScript/jQuery Graph and Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html5-canvas

How do I make the graph display the data the user entered in the app I am working on. There are two fields that the user has to enter information to and then that information has to be displayed on the graph for each day the user recorded the data so that the data can be tracked over time.

This is what I have so far:

```
function drawGraph(BPArr, BPUpper, BPLower) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("BPRecords") === null) {
        alert("No records exist.");

        $(location).attr("href", "#pageMenu");
    } else {
        setupCanvas();

        var BPArr = new Array();
        var DateArr = new Array();
        getBPHistory(BPArr, DateArr);

        var BPUpper = new Array(2);
        var BPLower = new Array(2);        

        drawLines(BPArr, BPUpper, BPLower, DateArr);
        labelAxes();
    }
}
```

And how do I change the label for the data?

```
function drawLines(BPArr, BPUpper, BPLower, DateArr) {
    var BPline = new RGraph.Line("GraphCanvas", BPArr, BPUpper, BPLower)
        .Set("labels", DateArr)
        .Set("colors", ["blue", "green", "red"])
        .Set("shadow", true)
        .Set("shadow.offsetx", 1)
        .Set("shadow.offsety", 1)
        .Set("linewidth", 1)
        .Set("numxticks", 6)
        .Set("scale.decimals", 2)
        .Set("xaxispos", "bottom")
        .Set("gutter.left", 40)
        .Set("tickmarks", "filledcircle")
        .Set("ticksize", 5)
        .Set("chart.labels.ingraph", [, , ["Systolic"], ,])
        .Set("chart.title", "Blood Pressure")
        .Draw();
}
```

I tried a couple different things and this is the one that kind of made sense to me but it was still not working.

```
    if (localStorage.getItem("BPRecords") ===
        null) {
        alert("No records exist.");

        $(location).attr("href", "#pageMenu");
    } else {
        setupCanvas();

        var BPArr = new Array();
        var DateArr = new Array();
        var BPUpper = new Array();
        var BPLower = new Array();
        getBPHistory(BPArr, DateArr);

        var BPUpper = new Array(2);
        var BPLower = new Array(2);
        
        BPUpper[0] = BPUpper[1] = 90;
        BPUpper[0] = BPUpper[1] = 120;
        BPUpper[0] = BPUpper[1] = 140;
        BPUpper[0] = BPUpper[1] = 190;

        BPLower[0] = BPLower[1] = 60;
        BPLower[0] = BPLower[1] = 80;        
        BPLower[0] = BPLower[1] = 90;        
        BPLower[0] = BPLower[1] = 100;
        
        drawLines(BPArr, BPUpper, BPLower, DateArr);
        labelAxes();
    }
    getBPbounds(BPLower, BPUpper);
}
```